# Modify Javascript to remove variables

Tags: javascript

I took some Javascript code originally meant to send users to different domains based on their location and changed it to make it so it just sends user to one location. The problem: It's rather redundant. Would someone be able to provide the code that just uses one domain? Thank you

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var redirect = (function () {
    /* This implements the actual redirection. */
    var redirectBrowser = function (site) {
        var uri = "http://" + site + ".google.com/";
        window.location = uri;
    };

    /* These are the country codes for the countries we have sites for.
     * We will check to see if a visitor is coming from one of these countries.
     * If they are, we redirect them to the country-specific site. If not, we
     * redirect them to world.example.com */
    var sites = {
        "WA": true

    };
    var defaultSite = "www";

    var onSuccess = function (geoipResponse) {
        /* There's no guarantee that a successful response object
         * has any particular property, so we need to code defensively. */
        if (!geoipResponse.city.iso_code) {
            redirectBrowser("www");
            return;
        }

        /* ISO country codes are in upper case. */
        var code = geoipResponse.city.iso_code.toLowerCase();

        if ( sites[code] ) {
            redirectBrowser(code);
        }
        else {
            redirectBrowser("www");
        }
    };

    /* We don't really care what the error is, we'll send them
     * to the default site. */
    var onError = function (error) {
        redirectBrowser("www");
    };

    return function () {
        geoip2.city( onSuccess, onError );
    };
}());

redirect();
</script>
```

Comment: One domain for what?

Comment: Isn't the answer within the code you posted?

Comment: The code above takes www and appends it to a domain. Originally used to do something like send canadian visitors to canada.domain.com or mexican visitors to mexico.domain.com. I swapped it out with "www" but it's redundant since I'm sending to only one domain.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: How does it make no sense? It's taken directly from MaxMind's sample: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/#Redirect_Users_to_a_Country-Specific_Site - the only difference is I needed it to redirect to one site, not multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var onError = function(e) {
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
};
geoip2.city(function(geo) {
    if(geo.city.iso_code) {
        switch(geo.city.iso_code.toLowerCase()) {
            case "wa": window.location = "http://wa.google.com/"; break;
            default: onError(0);
        }
    } else onError(0);
}, onError );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. What exactly am I replacing?

Comment: The script is redirecting users based on a specific location (in this example: WA) and everyone else with an IP that doesn't resolve to this region is not directed.

Comment: No, you modified the code so that it always redirects to http://www.google.com/ so I provided you with a much shorter version of the code that does the exact same thing

Comment: It only redirects to google when the region matches WA. It does not redirect everyone to google. I have it live on 3 sites right now and only WA region users are being redirected.

Comment: Please note I could have used an if statement in place of the switch but I figured I would retain the ability for the script to be able to redirect to other locations.